# D3 choropleth tooltip - change default "undefined"

Tags: d3.js, choropleth

I've made a working choropleth worldmap to show which countries contributed to a certain process (mainly following this helpful example: https://suffenus.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/making-interactive-maps-with-d3-for-total-beginners/).

I end up with paired values such as: United State: 10

Where a country didn't participate or isn't on my list, is it possible to change the tooltip from "undefined" to "0" (zero) or "N/A", etc. ?

The section of code relating to the tooltip call is here:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this).transition().duration(300).style("opacity", 1);
        div.transition().duration(300)
            .style("opacity", 1)
        div.text([d.id] + " : " + (SubsByCountry[d.id])) //<--THIS LINE
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 30) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        d3.select(this)
            .transition().duration(300)
            .style("opacity", 0.8);
        div.transition().duration(300)
            .style("opacity", 0);
    })
```

I'm actually not even sure where to start, but will revise this question if I come up with anything useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Simply check whether `SubsByCountry` has the key you're looking for. How is `SubsByCountry` defined?

Comment: Thanks. `SubsByCountry` is defined as `SubsByCountry[d.name] = +d.submissions;`. Here's a fiddle with a little more detail: http://jsfiddle.net/cajmcmahon/awur3dLk/.

Comment: Ok, so you would simply check `SubsByCountry[d.name] === null`.

Comment: Did Lars' comment help or do you still need help?

Comment: I'm working with `if (SubsByCountry === null) { return '0'; }` but not sure if correct or where to put it. Have tried right after the `div.text([d.id]` as well as outside the function but no luck so far. Will keep trying...

Comment: Haven't got the mouseover/tooltip to work yet, but I got the 'null' countries to turn red... `.style("fill", function(d) {
            if (SubsByCountry[d.id] === undefined) {return "red"}
            else  { return color(SubsByCountry[d.id]); }
        ;})`

Comment: Been trying this all day with various permutations. Still stuck. I'm not sure where to put the `SubsByCountry[d.name] === null`. Should it be a function? Should it be a `var`? etc. Would appreciate any additional pointers.